# Material UI element adding custom margin

Tags: reactjs, sass, material-ui, margin

I have this project where I try to use Material UI input elements. But when I try to add some custom styling I can't add a margin around the elements. I also added a background color to try if the element is getting to the scss style. The background color works but I don't seem to get the margin to work.

Here is an example of a input element:

```
import styles from "./registration.module.scss";

...

<TextField
            className={styles.formElement}
            id="name"
            label="Familienaam"
            variant="outlined"
            value={this.state.name}
            onChange={(e) => this.handleInputChanged("name", e.target.value)}
            helperText={
              this.state.errorMessage.name && this.state.errorMessage.name
            }
            error={!!this.state.errorMessage.name}
          />
```

This is the scss file with the style.

```
.formElement {
  margin: 10rem 10rem;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Try like this first : className="formElement" and import your scss just like that : 
import "./registration.module.scss";

Comment: Ciao @Stephen, scss with Material UI is a painful choice ... Do you accept a simple css answer or is to much stupid? :)